# Problems with Angular2.o0 decorators

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I can't seem to get `Angular2.0` under test. Every time I use an injector decorator I get an error about a missing file / shim. `reflect-metadata` shim is required when using class decorators';

I've tried importing my way around it

```
 import {CalendarBuilder} from './CalendarBuilder';
 import 'reflect-metadata';
 import 'zone.js'
```

But no Angular says no likey.

Here is the contents of my package - a modified AngularExample, it needs trimming. Can anyone please please help?

```
{   
"name": "angular2-quickstart",   
"version": "1.0.0",   
"scripts": {
     "test": "live-server --open=app/unit-tests.html",
     "tsc": "tsc",
     "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
     "lite": "lite-server",
     "go": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" "
},   
 "license": "ISC",
 "dependencies": {
     "angular2": "2.0.0-alpha.53",
     "chai": "^3.4.1",
     "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
     "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
     "gulp": "^3.9.0",
     "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.2",
     "rxjs": "5.0.0-alpha.14",
     "systemjs": "0.19.6",
     "underscore": "^1.8.3",
     "zone.js": "^0.5.8"   },
     "devDependencies": {
     "concurrently": "^1.0.0",
     "es6-shim": "^0.33.13",
     "gulp-jasmine": "^2.2.1",
     "gulp-mocha": "^2.2.0",
     "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
     "jspm": "^0.16.18",
     "lite-server": "^1.3.1",
     "live-server": "^0.9.0",
     "requirejs": "^2.1.22",
     "system-npm": "^0.4.2",
     "typescript": "^1.7.3"
 }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you should put `zone.js` in first place and `reflect-metadata` in second place. Besides that do not import them, the best approach is to add `angular2-polyfills.js` in your script tags.

Comment: Hey Eric, Thanks for your response I'm a noob to Angular and the JS ecosystem so can I ask you what you mean? I am not running the tests via a browser, so  how do I add the polysfill script to be included if I can't import it? I am running the tests via mocha in WebStorm. Thanks again man really appreciate it.

Also, this is a TypeScript project if that makes a difference?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by importing the `npm` package and referencing the type definition at the top of the test:

```
/// <reference path="../../type-definitions/reflect-metadata.d.ts"" />
require("reflect-metadata");
```

Comment: Hmm.. You solved it by importing what npm package and referencing the definitions at the top of what file?

Answer (score 0):

You can take care of the lack of `zone.js` and `reflect-metadata` by including the polyfills that are supplied with Angular 2.  Toss this into your index.html file:

```
<script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.min.js"></script>
```

You might have to change the path to fit your particular setup, but the important part is to know that the script is located in the `angular2/bundles` section of your `node_modules` folder.

Comment: Hey Michael,

Unfortunately I still get the same error. This is using a Mocha configuration in WebStorm

"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\dev\angular-scheduler\node_modules\mocha\bin\_mocha --ui bdd --reporter C:/dev/angular-scheduler/app/src/builders/CalendarBuilder-spec.js

C:\dev\angular-scheduler\node_modules\angular2\src\core\util\decorators.js:157
    throw 'reflect-metadata shim is required when using class decorators';
    ^
reflect-metadata shim is required when using class decorators

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: I see.  Perhaps you can paste more of your environment into the question.